# Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0 mailFolder id not unique?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

**My folder structure**

```
Inbox
  |- FolderA
  |   |-ChildA1
  |   |-ChildA2 ect.
  |
  |- FolderB
      |-ChildB1
      |-ChildB2 ect.
```

**The problem**

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0) is stated that the id-property for a mailFolder is unique. But several childs from FolderA does have the same id's as childs from FolderB.

*a child of FolderA*

```
Array
(
    [id] => AAMkADc3NmMwNWE3<...>aXeP4l9AAAH2RGbAAA=
    [displayName] => childAx
    [parentFolderId] => AAMkADc3NmMwNWE3<...>aXeP4l9AAAETiFqAAA=
    ...
)
```

*a child of FolderB*

```
(
    [id] => AAMkADc3NmMwNWE3<...>aXeP4l9AAAH2RGBAAA=
    [displayName] => childBx
    [parentFolderId] => AAMkADc3NmMwNWE3<...>aXeP4l9AAAETiFtAAA=
    ... 
)
```

As shown multiple mailFolders does have the same id.

**Steps I took**

Using `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/Inbox/childFolders` I get the id's for FolderA and FolderB. After that I get the childFolders for both folderA and folderB via `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/childFolders`

When using `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}` I get the mailFolder data from one of the folders with the same id's. How can I point out to another? Using a combination of the parentId and id?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your issue. I have however noted that the ids are similar to some extent but not the same value. There is at least one digit difference. See below I have four sub children and each have a unique id with largely the first parts being the same

Folder A
[image]

Folder B
[image]

If you see any duplicate folder ids to exact matches, you may need to create a support request.

Comment: The problem was a case problem. I put the id's in an Access database but that is case-insensitive.
Problem solved!